# Не запускается тестовая программа с opengl в ubuntu 20 04

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

Я нашел пример проги с opengl. Вот он:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void Reshape(int width, int height)
{
  glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluOrtho2D(-1, 1, -1, 1);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void Draw(void)
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
  glLineWidth(1);

  glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2f(0, 0.5f);  
    glVertex2f(0, -0.5f);  
  glEnd();

  glFlush();  
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitWindowSize(400, 300);
  glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);

  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB);
  glutCreateWindow("Romka Demo");

  glutReshapeFunc(Reshape);
  glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
  glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;
}
```

Компилировал со всеми нужными флагами:

```
g++ test.cpp -o firstOpenGLApp -L/usr/X11R6/lib/ -lGL -lGLU -lglut
```

но при запуске вылетает с такой ошибкой:
`freeglut (./firstOpenGLApp): failed to connect to a Wayland compositor` 
Сразу говорю, что гугление ошибки проблему не исправило.
И еще, на всякий случай: у меня установлена cuda 10.2

Answer (score 0):

NVIDIA (со своими нативными драйверами и CUDA) не дружит с Wayland, об этом много написано (см. https://linux-ru.ru/viewtopic.php?f=32&p=24358#p24357). Нужно заменить Wayland на X11 (Xorg).

Comment: А как это сделать?

Comment: $echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE выдает Х11